# Help understanding transactions on Blockchain.info

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info

Take a look at this address: https://blockchain.info/address/138oqqr5gficMb3sHDPYxe4GiMWEg7Zozp

Why there are two transactions with the same amount of BTC (one with green arrow and one with red arrow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Green arrow means incoming funds to this address

Red arrow means outgoing from.

There is not obligatory that the number of incoming transactions is equal to the number of outgoing ones. For this particular address there are 14 incoming and 14 outgoing transactions. This address seems to be some kind of mixer or/and technical address of some service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In reality, this is a BTC address of an account on Bittrex. As I know, the last transaction with 0.01775990BTC is a deposit transaction and there is not any spent relative to this amount of BTC. I just wonder why the amount of incoming and spent is always equaled. May I miss something?

Comment: if you (or somebody else) deposit funds on exchange this does not mean that your funds will stay there. Now the funds belong to exchange. And exchange uses them for withdrawal requests. This is how all financial organizations work.

Comment: Thank @amaclin. Maybe I understand what happened. I will mark your answer as correct.